# Flask api endpoint with multiple query parameters

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm sure there is probably a duplicate of this question somewhere but I don't know what the right wording is for the question I have.

I have endpoints that I want to reach and I ran `curl` commands on them:

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:5001/job/task/?job_type=medicine&task_type=research
curl http://0.0.0.0:5001/job/task/?job_type=medicine&task_type=research&job_id=123
```

The errors that I am getting for both are:

```
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

A part of my code is shown below, and I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I'm using `api.add_resource`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):

    def get(self,job_type,task_type,task_id = None):
        if not task_id:
            return {"job_type":job_type,"task_type":task_type}
        return {"job_type":job_type,"task_type":task_type,"job_id":job_id}

api.add_resource(Test, '/job/task/?<string:job_type>&<string:task_type>', '/job/task/?<string:job_type>&<string:task_type>&<int:job_id>')
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flask route

```
api.add_resource(Test, '/job/task/?<string:job_type>&<string:task_type>', '/job/task/?<string:job_type>&<string:task_type>&<int:job_id>')
```

will translated by flask into

```
/job/task/?job_type&task_type
```

not

```
/job/task/?job_type=xxx&task_type=yyy
```

That causes endpoint not found error.

**Solution**

You can access the query string using `request.args` (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args)

so, your url definition is should looks like

```
api.add_resource(Test, '/job/task/')
```

and in your view

```
from flask import request
.....

    def get(self):
        job_type = request.args.get("job_type")
        task_type = request.args.get("task_type")
        task_id = request.args.get("task_id")

        if not task_id:
            return {"job_type":job_type,"task_type":task_type}
        return {"job_type":job_type,"task_type":task_type,"job_id":job_id}
```

**Another solutions**:

1. use marshal https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_restful.marshal
2. use reqparse https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reqparse.RequestParser.parse_args